# How to block local release of the eclipse made for artifactory repository

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, artifactory

I´m working with Maven 3, eclipse Helios and Jenkins e Artifactory. During the execution of release plugin one of the steps that this plugin is doing, is publish in artifactory the generated release. In my organization, we have the following issue:

Only the manage of configuration can run the release through Jenkins with release-plugin, but any developer can run the release plugin through console and this execution will overwrite the release published in artifactory.

I´m looking around artifactory configurations and all developer users are with read permissions but they can update release local in artifactory.

There are any solution to block or disable the execution of local release from eclipse through Jenkins?

Thanks if anyone can help me!

Comment: What do you mean by a "Local Release" Ideally Maven Release Plugin should be used by only Jenkins and the developers should not run it. One way to avoid developers to make release is to disallow them any privilege to deploy to artifactory. In any case, the developers can call release:prepare which will end up creating a tag in the SCM.

Comment: exactly what I want know... how to disallow then privileges to upload release on artifactory? Because I looked to Artifactory and all users have just read permission in all repositories.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggets using [Artifactory's release management](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Release+Management) for Jenkins, which is part of the [Jenkins Artifactory plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin).
This will allow you to run release management purely from Jenkins, possibly with a dedicated user, and also run staging and promotion on releases.

Releasing/staging would typically be done to a dedicated repo in Artifactory which only the Jenkins release user has write permissions for.

The release management functionality in the Jenkins Artifactory plugin is a complete replacement for the maven release plugin (and for the Jenkins m2release plugin which is based on the latter), that is:

- Faster and involves less (unnecessary) rebuild cycles
- Integrates your existing Maven and SCM Jenkins configs
- More flexible in how versions can be applied
- Offers robust rollbacks
- Also works for non-Maven build types

Answer (score 0):

Move release plugin to [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) (it should not be activate by default). Activate profile only when you run build on jenkins. (for profile name jenkins use `mvn <goals> -Pjenkins`)

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions